# Passive FTP from EC2 Linux Instance stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp

I need to pull files from a vendor's ftp server The code (php) works fine in my local ubuntu instance and also from my Mac.  It was working fine in AWS (and still does when connecting to a different vendor).  It stopped working for a particular vendor (case opened with them). The code connects, changes directories, and retrieves a list of remote files without a problem.  The issue arises when I try to do an ftp_get of the remote file. It hangs and then times out. Yes, I'm using passive mode.

I tried to replicate the behavior using the standard linux ftp client (AWS Linux). Again, I can connect, change directories, but when I try to list the contents of the directory that has files, I get the following message and then it hangs indefinitely: 227 Entering Passive Mode (64,156,167,125,173,169) 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.

Is there anything I can do on my end to work around this or is the problem on the vendor side and I'm stuck until they respond to my ticket?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like aws security group that is in place does not allow opened ports for passive mode of FTP to get connected, once it's opening data connection on port assigned in ftp configuration file, I wouldn't say you can do anything about than try the active mode :)

Comment: Well I set up a new server running Ubuntu instead of AWS Linux and it all works just fine using the same security group. Bizarre.